# Returning a single row

Tags: c#, ado.net, asp.net-3.5

I'm trying to return a single row from a database:

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"]))
{
    using (command = new SqlCommand(@"select top 1 col_1, col_2 from table1", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read();
            return reader["col_1"];
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)
>   Line 90: return reader["col_1"];

I'm sure I am making a really obvious mistake, but I can't seem to find any single row examples, all I examples I find are for multiple returned rows using a `while loop`.

Comment: Btw,you're returning a single cell and not a single row! If that's what you want, then look into `command.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: @banging, that sounds spoton.  However, is it possible to return a single string instead of an integer using ExecuteScalar?

Comment: `ExecuteScalar()` returns an Object so you'll have to cast it appropriately like so `(string)command.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`reader["col_1"]` returns `object`.

You want something like `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("col_1"))`.

Edit -> I just wanted to add a note here that, in addition to the concerns others have raised, a `SELECT TOP` without an `ORDER BY` can give you random results based on schema changes and/or merry-go-round scans.

Answer (score 13):

This is how I would style (and fix) the code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"]))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"select top 1 col_1, col_2 from table1", connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read()) // Don't assume we have any rows.
        {
            int ord = reader.GetOrdinal("col_1");
            return reader.GetString(ord); // Handles nulls and empty strings.
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Using the index `reader[]` will give you `object` types, these need casting. However, I hardly touch that style and always favour the slightly more verbose, but more robust use of ordinals and asking for types in a strongly-typed manner.

If you only need the value in the first column of the first row, you can use `ExecuteScalar` instead, again this returns an object that can be cast and doesn't need a reader:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"]))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"select top 1 col_1, col_2 from table1", connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    return result == null ? "" : (string)result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the return type. The method you are in is expecting you to return a string, but `reader["col_1"]` is an object. I suggest returning `reader["col_1"].ToString()` or `Convert.ToString(reader["col_1"])`.

Comment: I have to disagree with calling ToString as this will continue to work even if the underlying type changes. In my opinion, if that changes away from string I'd like to get an error telling me as much. If it is *really* a string, cast it `(string)reader[""]` or better yet, ask for it `reader.GetString(0)`.

Comment: This doesn't play nice with nulls. Use `Convert.ToString(reader["col_1"])` instead..

Answer (score 5):

To me it seems, you don't want a single row, only a single value:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
Object returnValue;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 col_name FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection.Open();

returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

sqlConnection.Close();

return returnValue.ToString(); //Note you have to cast it to your desired data type
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
 using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
 {
      reader.Read();
      return reader["col_1"];
 }
```

You need to cast the `reader["col_1"]` to string, either `reader["col_1"].ToString()` or `reader.GetString(0)` like:

```
return reader.GetString(0);
```

Comment: That will return the value of `col_2`, not `col_1`.

Comment: Actually, `col_1` is the first column - but the column indices are **zero-based** so you should use `reader.GetString(0)` to get `col_1` as a string...

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `if` statement if your query only returns one value

```
[...]
string x = string.Empty;
if(reader.Read()) {
    // make sure the value is not DBNull
    if(DBNull.Value != reader["col_1"]) {
       x = reader.GetString(0);
    }
}
[...]
```

Comment: I have to disagree with calling `ToString` as this will continue to work even if the database type changes. In my opinion, if that changes away from `string` I'd like to get an error telling me as much. If it is *really* a string, cast it `(string)reader[""]` or better yet, ask for it `reader.GetString(0)`.

Comment: Note that I previously wrote `var x = ...` so I'm specifying the type with `ToString()`, but yeah, `reader.GetString(0)` is better

Comment: No I wasn't saying that the type in code would be incorrect, I am saying it would hide issues with the fact that the value in the database is no longer a string, as `.ToString` will successfully convert anything other than `null` into a string.

Comment: I get it, but since you mentioned, I've added a check for `DBNull` and I'm for using built-in functions. That's why I changed.

Answer (score 3):

`reader["col_1"]` returns an `object`. I assume your function has a return type of `string`, which is where the error is coming from, it cannot implicitly convert the `object` to a `string`.

You probably expect a string returned from col_1 so you can just cast it: `(string)reader["col_1"]`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can use the cast `(string)reader["col_1"]`. You are probably expecting a string and `reader["col_1"]` is an `object`.

Answer (score 2):

the reader returns object which you should cast it to what you need, in this case a string.

you can use any of this codes :

`return reader.GetString(0);`

`return reader["col_1"].ToString();`

`return Convert.ToString(reader["col_1"]);`

`return reader["col_1"] as string;`

but dont forget to close the connection and reader before leaving the function.

```
string ret = reader.GetString(0);
reader.Close();
connection.Close();
return ret;
```

Comment: He has everything in `using` so he doesn't need to explicitly close anything!

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps to select a single colume, and display them.

```
    //create a connection
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

    //open the connection
    sqlConnection.Open();

    //Your command query string
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 col_name FROM Customers";


    //Execute the reader
    SqlDataReader result  = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    result.Read();

    //close the connection
    sqlConnection.Close();

    return result["coiumn_name"].ToString();
```