# DataTable Returns no records from Database. Why is that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, datatable, webforms

I want to return records on the basis of two parameters, `EmployeeNo` and `Password`. What i mean is that when a user enter his/her credentials like `EmployeeNo` and `Password` then first program check if its present in the database or not. But i have a problem with the datatable. Datatable has no rows. Following is my code, which seems Okay to me but i have no idea why its not working. Here is my code

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Base.GetConnection))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableUserProfile WHERE UserEmpNum=@UserEmpNum and UserPassword=@UserPassword", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmpNum", tbEmpNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", tbPassword.Text);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ad.Fill(dt);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                if (cbRememberLogin.Checked)
                {
                    Response.Cookies["UEmpNo"].Value = tbEmpNumber.Text;
                    Response.Cookies["UPass"].Value = tbPassword.Text;
                    Response.Cookies["UEmpNo"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
                    Response.Cookies["UPass"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Cookies["UEmpNo"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    Response.Cookies["UPass"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                }

                Session["UserEmployee"] = tbEmpNumber.Text;
                Response.Redirect("~/UserProfile.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

When i put my program on a debug mode, it retrieve nothing, Here is the pic
[image]

Here is my Database Table
[image]

Comment: I can't see why, other than maybe unexpected whitespace in a text box. But then I'm having a hard time getting past the fact that you have *passwords stored in clear text*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397946/returning-a-single-row)

Comment: No, this is just i am checking. I'll be using `MD5` for password encryption. The `White Spaces` is not the problem here.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `tbEmpNumber.Text`? `tbPassword.Text`? `tbEmpNumber.Text.Length`? `tbPassword.Text.Length`? _Please check all of them in the Immediate Window - do not guess._ Please show us a screenshot of the **exact same query** running in Management Studio, such that we can see the query **and** the results.

Comment: What do you mean by `it returns NULL`? Do you mean that `dt.Rows.Count` is 0? Something else?

Comment: `tbEmpNumber.Text` returns the same value `AFFAQ`, and `tbPassword.Text` returns `000`. `[Correct Values]`.

Comment: Please provide all values I asked for, not just some. Also please include the screenshot.

Comment: I strongly suspect you are searching by `UserEmpNum` when you **meant** to search by `UserName`. I say that only since `AFFAQ` doesn't **sound** like an `EmpNum`.

Comment: You are right man. I am such a fool. Thank you. It works. I was searching for `UserEmpNum` while i was busy providing `UserName`. You are a champ.

Comment: Please write your answer in the answer box so that i verify. Bundle of thanks man.

Comment: Nah, it is a typo. I won't take credit for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt != null)
        {
            gvr_rkit.DataSource = dt;
            gvr_rkit.DataBind();
        }
```

SqlDataAdapter is a part of the ADO.NET Data Provider. SqlDataAdapter provides the communication between the Dataset and the Data Source with the help of SqlConnection Object .The SqlDataAdapter works with the DataSet to provide a disconnected data retrieval mechanism.

he SelectCommand property of the SqlDataAdapter is a Command object that retrieves data from the data source. The Fill method of the DataAdapter is used to populate a DataSet with the results of the SelectCommand .  Fill method takes as its arguments a DataSet to be populated, and a DataTable object , or the name of the DataTable to be filled with the rows returned from the SelectCommand

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This may be copied from http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/selectcommand-sqlserver.htm .